# \thispagestyle{empty} with longtable

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, longtable, landscape

I have a `longtable` and `landscape` table that spans 3 pages. I don't want a page number to be displayed on any of these 3 pages. However, setting `\thispagestyle{empty}` just *preceding* the commencement of the table will only cause the first of the 3 page numbers to be removed.

***QUESTION***: How do I make it such that all 3 page numbers are removed, while at the same time preserving all my other page numbers?

---

I haven't been able to construct a MWE due to inexperience with `lipsum`. Here's my attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{longtable}
\lipsum[500]
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill This is the correct solution. Submit answer for points.

Comment: oooops sorry @PeterGrill I just posted that answer before I saw your comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :-) NP. You helped me with another answer today (well yesterday for you), so we'll consider that even.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `landscape` involves a forced page break there is no problem in using

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

before the table and

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

after it (or whatever page style you are using in the rest of the document).